# MODULE_NOT_FOUND Error, after successfully installing a npm module - require(module);

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I get a MODULE_NOT_FOUND error after successfully installing the external module "file" with npm. It appears in the project folder with all its files as usual, the dependencies in the json file are also there. It happens with every npm package. I already reinstalled npm and tried different LTS versions of npm. I double checked the json file that the dependencies are corret.

This is the error message:

```html
phila@DESKTOP-68STT9S MINGW64 /g/My Drive/Work - Software/WebDevelopmentCourse/Web Development/introNPMNODE
$ node test.js
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'file'    
Require stack:
- G:\My Drive\Work - Software\WebDevelopmentCourse\Web Development\introNPMNODE\test.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (G:\My Drive\Work - Software\WebDevelopmentCourse\Web Development\introNPMNODE\test.js:1:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'G:\\My Drive\\Work - Software\\WebDevelopmentCourse\\Web Development\\introNPMNODE\\test.js'
  ]
}
```

This is the json file:

```html
{
  "name": "intronpmnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "phil",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.3",
    "file": "^0.2.2"
  }
}
```

the javascript "test.js" file:

```html
var file = require("file");
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are pointing the node command to a file that exists on your file system and There are no spaces between words, delete **node_modules** and **package-lock.json**, re-install dependencies and restart your IDE.

If the error is not resolved, try to delete your and (not) files, re-run and restart your IDE.`node_modules` `package-lock.json` `package.json` `npm install`

delete **node_modules** and **package-lock.json**

```
rm -rf node_modules

rm -f package-lock.json
```

clean npm cache

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install
```

Comment: I found a solution, however your approach did not work. I made a new folder at C:/testproject/project  and installed npm for that folder, same as I did before actually. It worked. Maybe node does not like spaces within a file path, or maybe it did not like my G: drive which was a google drive synced folder. IDK, but making a new project folder at a path without spaces and without google drive synced made it work.